# Using Vue CLI in Cloud9 IDE (container): 'Invalid Host Header'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server, vue-cli

I am trying to use Vue CLI on cloud 9, and followed all the installation guides, but I am not a backend person, so I am having a hard time figuring out why the page shows 'Invalid Host header' on every page.

This is what I did:

- Created a new workspace called `practice`
- Installed vue via `npm install vue`
- Installed vue cli via `npm install @vue/cli`
- Installed whatever this is `npm install @vue-cli-service-global` (answer on what this is would be appreciated)
- Created a project called `login-system` via `vue create login-system`
- Ran `vue serve`

When the server started after that command, I went to http://practice-myusername.c9user.io:8080, where it simply said "Invalid Host header" There was no error in the server console or client console. Had the server failed to start, it would show a page that said "No app is running here..." by default or something like that.

Going to http://practice-myusername.c9user.io or http://practice-myusername.c9user.io/anywhere or http://practice-myusername.c9user.io/aradfa99asd all produced the same result.

Whenver I run the server through that last item, `vue serve` the server tab in the IDE says

> You may be using the wrong PORT & IP for your server application. Try passing $PORT and $IP to properly launch your application. You can find more information in [our docs](https://docs.c9.io/docs/running-and-debugging-code)

I haven't found the doc to be too useful in solving my problem.

What's going on? Again, I don't know any backend stuff, so detailed answer/response would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

A bit of digging keeps showing that I should add this to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
 devServer: {
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
 }
```

I understand that Vue CLI builds on top of webpack, but I can't find the config file anywhere, and creating one doesn't seem to help. I also came across a solution about `vue.config.js` but I don't know how to structure the content inside it, nor which directory to put it in.

Answer (score 6):

In order for `vue-cli` to pick up `vue.config.js`, it should be located in the same folder as `package.json` and `src` folder.

Vue-cli checks if file exists and if object is exported from it.
Configuration options can be found in [official vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config) and [devServer](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) options specifically. Note that `vue-cli` provides custom options to configure app, that is meant to make our life easier, such as `devServer`, `outputDir`, etc, while efficiently merging them into a complete `webpack.config.js`. Thus without exposing config file itself, it prevents us from a lot of trouble of debugging webpack, while keeping enough control to customize the config.

Anyway, following content of `vue.config.js` will adjust `webpack` configuration to solve your issue:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  // ... other options
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I still received the "You may be using the wrong $PORT..." message, but hitting Preview > Preview Running Application (after updating vue.config.js) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

aBiscuit solution worked, but Hot Module Reloading (HMR) isn't working. This seems to be an easy fix...

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    public: `${process.env.C9_PID}.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`,
  },
  // ... other options
}
```

Replace `us-east-1` with the correct region if necessary.